Android Studio New Empty Activity Kotlin-based project - default code: is there a way to override this?
When I create a new Empty Activity project in Android Studio (Koala 2024.1.1. patch) Android studio creates a MainActivity.kt file with this code in the MainActivity class:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            FlowDemoTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Just created a new Empty Activity project.  Created it as always with no coding problems or errors.
Is there a way to change this default code to implement the Surface object instead of Scaffold?  Most training videos/books (and yes, I am just learning this stuff now) use Surface instead of Scaffold. Couldn't find anyplace to change this setting if this is even possible?
Thanks in advance,
Scott M.

No, there isn't.  But it seems a trivial change to make to it yourself after generation.  I'm also surprised this was created by an "empty Activity", as this is not empty.  Are you sure you picked the correct option?

As an aside-  neither scaffold nor Surface is the right thing to use as a complete beginner, but Scaffold seems closer to it.

It just recently changed (Koala or Jellyfish?): Before it was Surface, now it is a Scaffold. But how often do you even create new projects so that changing the defaults would net you a win?

Gentlemen, your responses are appreciated very much.  Not much of a change after creating a new project for sure.   Going through the learning process, I found that I am creating new projects all the time.  That will most likely end when I become a "real android developer"...not there yet.  Thanks for the insight!!!
